# Best Practice for Creating a class that has Different Table Names but same properties

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have two tables that have different names but have the same column names, what is the best way to go about creating my class so i dont have to duplicate the same assignment.

EX: Table1 has (Date, Name, Person, ID). Table2 has (Date,Name,Person,ID). I can't combine both tables into one either. So what would be my options? I am using Linq To Sql to generate the classes for me.

Comment: Why can't it be 1 table?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data about Person, Date, Name into third table and in those 2 use this table, and I recommend to use Entity Framework ORM